# Linking different User with my Google assistant App

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am developing an app for google assistant, an app also contains chat conversation between the members.
So, is there any way to link different user with my App.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the account linking feature: https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking

However, you will need your own OAuth server.

Once account linking is set up, you can enable your app to trigger account linking in two ways: when your app is invoked or during a conversation within your app.